# Need assistance in determining increased probability

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, t-test

it has been awhile since I've taken a statistics course and have been trying to refresh myself with material online but have become stuck and needed a clarification so I was hoping you could help.

I have two groups that I have determined their means to be statistcially different with a 95% CI through a two sample t-test by rejecting the null hypothesis.  Below are the Minitab results:

[image: minitab]

The question I'm trying to solve is this:  Group 1 is the average score for those who win ended up winning later and Group 2 is the average score for those who ended up losing later.  How would I calculate the probability of someone losing (falling into group 2) if their score is below the mean of those winning (group 1).  To elaborate, if someone's score was 23, using the information we have, how can I determine the probability they would end up in group 2 vs group 1... What about if their score fell to 21, etc...

Thank you for your time and any assistance you may provide would be much appreciated!